# Essential or nonessential sentence element?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> He looked at the skies fully saturated with blue paint.

or

> He looked at the skies, fully saturated with blue paint.

Is "fully saturated with blue paint" here an essential or nonessential element of the sentence and should it be separated by a comma?

Edit: removed *the* before *blue paint* as recommended by **chasly from UK**.

Comment: The second version gives me the impression that _he_ was full of blue paint, not the skies. So I would opt for the version without the comma.

Comment: Can't tell. "There were 10 similar-looking landscapes before John. How could he tell which one was the Constable? He looked at the skies fully saturated with the blue paint." //  "John liked the set of landscapes. He looked at the skies, fully saturated with the blue paint."

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, I agree. I feel the same way.

Comment: @Edwin What or who is the Sargent? Edit: Oh, a famous painter. Never mind.

Comment: So your question should be 'He looked at the skies, which were fully saturated with the blue paint.' vs 'He looked at the skies which were fully saturated with the blue paint.'

Comment: @Edwin Can I not omit "which were" in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, but then the question you say you're asking is not addressed by the first responder. Though I'd say that 'fully saturated with paint' is very unlikely to be used to refer to a human by the vast majority of native speakers.

Comment: There is an added problem here that subtly changes the meaning. I would expect, "...with blue paint." rather than  "...with **the** blue paint." Has the blue paint been mentioned before or is this the first we have heard of it? It makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: @Edwin Hmm. It's a tricky example. That's why I am seeking advice of other people. So, do you think it can be presented either way (depending on whether I want to emphasize that the sky have very rich blue color or treat it as additional and not particularly important information)?

Comment: @chasly it probably should be "...with blue paint." Thank you for spotting the mistake.

Comment: _You need to use a simpler pair of examples to see what's happening._ Listen to the man, talking about his parents. = Listen to the man: [he's] talking about his parents. //  Listen to the man talking about his parents. = Listen to the man – the one who is talking about his parents. In the second case (first variant), the reduced relative clause is **defining** (identifying which particular man).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- We may have had this discussion before, but if you use the *which/that* (non-restrictive/restrictive) distinction, your example becomes a bit clearer:   '*He looked at the skies, which were fully saturated with the blue paint*.' (NR) vs '*He looked at the skies that were fully saturated with the blue paint*.' (R)

Comment: @Jim No. If **everyone** accepted the which/that (non-restrictive/restrictive) distinction, a situation far from reality, this would make it clearer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- The way I see it, even if someone who does not typically make this distinction can look at this particular set of sentences with that distinction in mind, they may be able to more readily see the two meanings because of the different wording. Then if they want to say, "Ok, I see what you mean, but I just use *which* for both" - that's fine with me.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is bad writing to begin with.   It is not clear.  This is why there are so many opinions about what it means and how to "fix" it.  Bad writing always needs justification.  Good writing speaks for itself.

Without knowing what you want to convey to the reader, I can't offer any "fixes" for this.   Who is saturated with blue paint?  He or the sky?  What does saturated with blue paint mean?  Sponges are saturated but skies cannot be saturated...maybe with water moisture, which produces rain.

Keep it short and simple, and when you feel a reader might be confused, trust that instinct and rewrite from scratch.